# Drupal token for first image

Tags: drupal-7, token

I need use my 1st image URL for og:image metatag in my articles or use some default image in case of no image in it. How to do that? Thanx guys

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it works like a charm.
https://drupal.org/node/1284810#comment-5914820

Comment: Thanks for decision. It's a pity not token used. It is very hard to find something in custom code after long time)